# My "if" statement is not working as expected

Tags: c#, if-statement, unity-game-engine, swipe

In my `Unity C#` game for Android,  I want to detected when the closest gameobject to the character is the one im looking for (left), and, if the player of the game has not swiped left on the screen (swipeLeft), I want to change a value in my code called `strike`. But It is not working properly.

When Im in the game view the `leftSwipe` value does not work every time (It does when the if function is removed) and strike does not change at all. I would like to know how to fix this or is there is an alternative to this problem.

Here is the `if` statement:

```
if ((closestPlatform = left) && (leftSwipe = false)) { strike = 1; }
```

Here is the entire `C#` script:

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class SwipeChecker : MonoBehaviour
{

    public float maxTime;
    public float minSwipeDistance;

    float startTime;
    float endTime;

    Vector3 startPos;
    Vector3 endPos;

    float swipeDistance;
    float swipeTime;
    public float swipeScore;

    public GameObject left;
    public GameObject right;
    public GameObject up;
    public GameObject down;
    public GameObject swipeChecker;
    public GameObject[] platforms = new GameObject[5];

    public bool leftSwipe;
    public bool didntSwipe;

    public float strike;



    public GameObject closestPlatform;





    // Use this for initialization

    public GameObject FindClosestPlatform()
    {
        GameObject[] gos;
        GameObject[] gos2;
        GameObject[] gos3;
        GameObject[] gos4;
        gos = GameObject.FindGameObjectsWithTag("platform");

        GameObject closest = null;
        float distance = Mathf.Infinity;
        Vector3 position = transform.position;
        foreach (GameObject go in gos)

        {
            Vector3 diff = go.transform.position - position;
            float curDistance = diff.sqrMagnitude;
            if (curDistance < distance)
            {
                closest = go;
                distance = curDistance;
            }
        }
        return closest;
    }

public IEnumerator wait()
    {
        leftSwipe = true;
        yield return new WaitForSeconds(0.5f);
        leftSwipe = false;
    }



    void Start()
    {

    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {



        closestPlatform = FindClosestPlatform();


        if ((closestPlatform = left) && (leftSwipe = false))
        {
            strike = 1;
        }


        if (Input.touchCount > 0)
        {
            Touch touch = Input.GetTouch(0);

            if (touch.phase == TouchPhase.Began)
            {
                startTime = Time.time;
                startPos = touch.position;
            }
            else if (touch.phase == TouchPhase.Ended)
            {
                endTime = Time.time;
                endPos = touch.position;

                swipeDistance = (endPos - startPos).magnitude;
                swipeTime = endTime - startTime;

                if (swipeTime < maxTime && swipeDistance > minSwipeDistance)
                {
                    swipe();
                }
            }

        }

    }


    void swipe()
    {












            Vector2 distance = endPos - startPos;
            if (Mathf.Abs(distance.x) > Mathf.Abs(distance.y))
            {
                Debug.Log("Horizontal Swipe");
                if (distance.x > 0)
                {
                    Debug.Log("Right Swipe");
                }
                if (distance.x < 0)
                {
                    Debug.Log("Left Swipe");

                    StartCoroutine(wait());


                }

            }

            else if (Mathf.Abs(distance.x) < Mathf.Abs(distance.y))
            {
                Debug.Log("Vertical Swipe");
                if (distance.y > 0)
                {
                    Debug.Log("Up Swipe");
                }
                if (distance.y < 0)
                {
                    Debug.Log("Down Swipe");
                }
            }


        }




    }
```

Comment: In C#, it's generally considered bad practice to use public fields. All those fields should be marked `private`. To make them show up in the unity inspector, place a `[SerializeField]` attribute on them. If you need to access any of them outside of the class, wrap them in a *property*. That way, if you ever need to have something happen whenever the property is modified, it will be easy to make that change without having to change code throughout your entire project.

Answer (score 9):

```
if ((closestPlatform = left) && (leftSwipe = false)) { strike = 1; }
```

`=` is assignment.  `==` is comparison.

This will always be false, as it assigns `false` to `leftSwipe` and then uses it as the operand to `&&`.

You meant to write

```
if ((closestPlatform == left) && !leftSwipe) { strike = 1; }
```

Note that it is poor style to compare bools against `true` and `false`.  Instead of `if(x == true)` just say `if (x)`.  You wouldn't say "if the statement that it is raining is a true statement then close the window".  You'd just say "if it is raining then close the window". Instead of `if (x == false)` just say `if (!x)`.   You wouldn't say "if the statement that it is raining is a false statement then open the window".  You'd say "if it is not raining then open the window".  Keep it simple and you'll make fewer mistakes.

Comment: Thanks for the help.

Comment: @Terminal56: You're welcome. If you got an answer to your question, mark one of the answers as having answered your question please. That way people know not to come to this question and try to answer it.

Answer (score 4):

You're using assignment, not comparison.

```
if ((closestPlatform = left) && (leftSwipe = false)) { strike = 1; }
```

Replace "=" with "==".

Answer (score 0):

You are using assignment operator rather use comparison operators.

```
if ((closestPlatform == left) && (leftSwipe == false)) { strike = 1; }
```